# Fetch Still Hit After Purged Edge-Cache

Tags: caching, fetch, cloudflare

I have this API link that cloudflare cache in edge, and everytime the data(s) updated the backend will send to cloudflare's api to purge this link.

When I try with postman it work perfectly fine, got MISS when new data(s) came and got cached when try to fetch afterwards.

But when building frontend website using fetch no matter how hard I try it will always "HIT" cloudflare's cache even though my postman got "MISS".

[(Image) Postman "MISS"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2Rpy.png)

[(Image) Fetch Always "HIT"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qflul.png)

Answer (score 0):

Providing more details about your testing method would allow better guess. But offhand, sounds like after purging the cache you are testing Postman *first* each time? In which case makes sense that it would be a *MISS*, then followed up by browser test, it would be loaded into cache (from the Postman request)?